# finding first even element and outputting index

Tags: java, arrays

My program:

```
public static void evenval (int[] array ){
    int even=0;

    for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++) {

    while (r == array[r]) {
        if (array[r] % 2 ==0) {
            even = array[r];
            System.out.println("The first even number's index is:"+array[r]);
        }
```

I'm trying to make a loop where it finds the first even number in an array and get it to output it's index to the main method.

I'm stuck, please help.

Comment: What part of your description do you think this is doing? `while (r == array [r]){`

Comment: Remove the `while(r == array[r]){` part and add `break;` behind the System.outprintln() call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use just `for` loop like this:

```
    int even = 0;
    for (int r=0;r<array.length;r++){
       if (array[r] % 2 ==0){
        even = r; 
        break;  
         }        
        }
     System.out.println("The first even number's index is:"+ even );
```

Using the `break;` when find the even number.

For example if you want to find `100th` even number use this:

```
    int even = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int r=0;r<array.length;r++){
      if(array[r] % 2 ==0){
       if(count !=100){
         count++;
         }else{
           even = r; 
           break;  
         }
        }

        }
     System.out.println("The first even number's index is:"+ even );
```

Comment: What if we need to find the 100th even number?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a small method in your class and call it from main to do this for you and return the index or -1 if a valid even number is not found. :

```
public class EvenTest{
   int getFirstEvenIndex(int[] array){
       for (int r=0; r < array.length; r++){
            if (array[r] % 2 ==0){
                return r;
            }       
        }
        return -1;
   }

   public static void main(String... args){
        int[] arr = [3,5,1,2,7,8];
        EvenTest et = new EvenTest();
        System.out.println("First even is at index: " + et.getFirstEvenIndex(arr));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {5, 7, 1, 8, 9, 3,110};
        int evenCount =2;//required count ....for 100th even put evenCount = 100;
        evenval(array,evenCount);
    }

    public static void evenval(int[] array,int evenCount) {
        for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            if(array[i] % 2 == 0&&--evenCount==0) {
                System.out.println("the required even number is "+array[i]+" at index "+i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `while statement` in your code.

```
int even = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++) {

        if (array[r] % 2 == 0) {
            even = array[r];
            System.out.println("The first even number's index is:" + array[r]);
        }

    }
```

If you want to stop after finding first even number, just put `break` inside `if statement`

```
int even = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < array.length; r++) {

        if (array[r] % 2 == 0) {
            even = array[r];
            System.out.println("The first even number's index is:" + array[r]);
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a bitwise operation as well (performance wise, it's quicker):

```
 for (int n : array) {
     if ((n&1) == 0) {
         System.out.println("The first even number's index is:" + n);
         break;
     }
 }
```